# how to convert Russian string to Cyrillic?

Tags: c#, utf-8

im using one search concept in my application, if the user enters the search key word as russian text it throws an exception..**asp.net, c#..**

Eg:-

If i enterd this string it throws an exception **"сoгласoвания"** (Russian text), so i converted the text into like this

**" ñoãëàñoâàíèÿ "**, now it works..

in html we can do this with the help of meta tag

**meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF8"**

i dont know how to do in c#....

Please help me..

thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the resulting string representation? I see non-printable chars only.

Comment: Ah, that's easy: `myString.Replace("сoгласoвания", " ñoãëàñoâàíèÿ ")`. (OK, just kidding. I second sharptooth's and Anders' request for clarification.)

Comment: I'd say the first string is Cyrillic, but then again I'm not russian. Can you give us more background on what you want to do? Where will the second string go? What encoding do you want?

Comment: @Anders Forsgren: The first string is displayed in Cyrillic characters. No idea what the second one displays.

Comment: As a Russian I'm happy to say the first string is Cyrillic and the second string is gibberish. I actually don't see what he wants to do here - it seems he wants to convert perfectly good text to random characters.

Comment: @Michael: the second text must be Cyrillic in some old-fashioned encoding (like cp866), interpreted as UTF-8, or something like that.

Comment: @Michael Dmitry Azarkevich: u r rite..!!

Comment: <html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF8" /> </head> <body> сoгласoвания </body> </html> paste the above code in this link [ http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_charsets ] then u ppl's can understand what i want...

Answer (score 3):

Using [this](http://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en) site, I messed around with the text and got the original. It's encoded as widnows-1251 although there are other encodings that work. (windows-1254, windows-1252, iso8859-1, iso8859-9 and others)

In short, if you want to get the same output as the meta tag, encode it with the Encoding class (as mentioned by Vlad) initialized like this:

```
Encoding encode = new Encoding("windows-1251");
```

Comment: :- thanks for your reply, i tried but i didnt get that correct string, can you provide me full code..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Surely you need [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) class to change the encoding. Look up the example at the end of the MSDN article.

Comment: @vasmay That would be because you used the wrong encoding. See my answer for more info. Also, +1 for using framework classes :D

Comment: @Michael Dmitry Azarkevich:- thanks for your reply, i tried but i didnt get that correct string, can provide me a full code..Thanks in advance..